# Is there a multidimensional FindSequenceFunction for multi-parameter pattern discovery?

Tags: discrete

[`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) is a great tool for discovering formulas of sequences depending on a single index. [OEIS](https://oeis.org) is another tool for the case of integer sequences depending on a single index.

I often find myself looking for patterns in multi-dimensional sequences though, and the automated tools are quite lacking. Are there any automated tools for multidimensional pattern discovery? In my experience, not every multidimensional problem can be divided-and-conquered as the following simple example.

#### example

Here's a concrete example: imagine we are given the black-box generator

```
p[i_Integer, j_Integer] = Binomial[i, j];
```

and we need to discover its formula depending on two parameters $i$ and $j$. In this particularly easy example, we can get to the result by using `FindSequenceFunction` twice:

1. For every value of $j$ we can use `FindSequenceFunction` to discover a formula in $i$:

   ```
   Table[{j, FindSequenceFunction[Table[{i, p[i, j]}, {i, 0, 20}], i]}, {j, 0, 10}]
   ```

> $
> \left\{
>  \left\{0, 1\right\},
>  \left\{1, i\right\},
>  \left\{2, \frac{(i-1) i}{2}\right\},
>  \left\{3, \frac{(i-2) (i-1) i}{6}\right\},
>  \left\{4, \frac{(i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{24}\right\},
>  \left\{5, \frac{(i-4) (i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{120}\right\},
>  \left\{6, \frac{(i-5) (i-4) (i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{720}\right\},
>  \left\{7, \frac{(i-6) (i-5) (i-4) (i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{5040}\right\},
>  \left\{8, \frac{(i-7) (i-6) (i-5) (i-4) (i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{40320}\right\},
>  \left\{9, \frac{(i-8) (i-7) (i-6) (i-5) (i-4) (i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{362880}\right\},
>  \left\{10, \frac{(i-9) (i-8) (i-7) (i-6) (i-5) (i-4) (i-3) (i-2) (i-1) i}{3628800}\right\}
> \right\}
> $

2. We can then apply `FindSequenceFunction` again on this list of formulae:

   ```
   FindSequenceFunction[%, j]
   ```

> ((-1)^(2 + j) Pochhammer[-i, j])/Pochhammer[1, j]

This is close enough to the desired result that we can proceed with standard tools like `FunctionExpand` and `FullSimplify`.

Comment: I don't think there is still. But I would think it would be a very Mathematica thing to have. Have you suggested this feature to the Wolfram Community?