# Using FindSequenceFunction to solve the integral of the product of Legendre polynomials and power functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

The integral of the product of Legendre polynomials and power functions:

$I=\int_{-1}^1 x^n \mathrm{P}_l(x) \mathrm{d} x$

The calculation result from the textbook is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I 
& =0
\end{aligned} 
(n<l)$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I 
& =\frac{n !}{(n+l+1) ! !(n-l) ! !}\left[1+(-1)^{n-l}\right]
\end{aligned}
(n>=l)$$

Firstly, direct integration is unsuccessful:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Integrate[x^n*LegendreP[l, x], {x, -1, 1},  Assumptions -> Element[{l, n}, PositiveIntegers]]
```

(*   Failed   *)

**The result couldn't be obtained using `FindSequenceFunction`. Is it because the pattern is too complex or there are errors in the code?**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

int[n_Integer, l_Integer] := int[n, l] = Integrate[x^n*LegendreP[l, x], {x, -1, 1}]

Table[int[n, l], {n, 1, 7}, {l, 1, 8}] // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {"n" Range[1, 7], "l" Range[1, 8]}] &
```

Then,

```
Table[{l, FindSequenceFunction[Table[{n, int[n, l]}, {n, l, l + 20}], n]}, {l, 1, 10}]
```

(* {a long table} *)

```
FindSequenceFunction[%, l]
```

(* Failed *)

**Ref:**

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/297745/69835

[Is there a multidimensional FindSequenceFunction for multi-parameter pattern discovery?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199125/69835)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

int[n_Integer?Positive, l_Integer?Positive] := int[n, l] =
  Integrate[x^n*LegendreP[l, x], {x, -1, 1}]

Table[int[n, l], {n, 1, 7}, {l, 1, 8}] //
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {
     StringForm["n=``", #] & /@ Range[7],
     StringForm["l=``", #] & /@ Range[8]}] &
```

[image]

```
(tab1 = Table[{l, 
      FindSequenceFunction[Table[{n, int[n, l]}, {n, l, l + 20}], n]}, {l, 1, 
      20}] // FullSimplify)[[1 ;; 4]]
```

[image]

Convert `tab1` to `Piecewise` expressions

```
(tab2 = Simplify[{#[[1]], Piecewise[{
         {Simplify[#[[2]], Mod[n, 2] == 0], Mod[n, 2] == 0},
         {Simplify[#[[2]], Mod[n, 2] == 1], Mod[n, 2] == 1}}]} & /@
     tab1])[[1 ;; 4]]
```

[image]

Handle the even and odd values of `l` separately.

```
int2[n_Integer?Positive, l_Integer?Positive] = 
 Evaluate@Piecewise[{{Assuming[Mod[n, 2] == 1 && Mod[l, 2] == 1, 
      FindSequenceFunction[tab2[[1 ;; ;; 2]] // FullSimplify, l] //
       FullSimplify], Mod[n, 2] == 1 && Mod[l, 2] == 1},
    {Assuming[Mod[n, 2] == 0 && Mod[l, 2] == 0, 
      FindSequenceFunction[tab2[[2 ;; ;; 2]] // FullSimplify, l] //
       FullSimplify], Mod[n, 2] == 0 && Mod[l, 2] == 0}}]
```

[image]

Verifying that `int2` is equivalent to `int`

```
And @@ (Flatten@Table[int[n, l] == int2[n, l], {n, 1, 30}, {l, 1, 30}])

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Not** using **FindSequenceFunction**:

$$P_l(x)=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{2^{-j-k} (-x)^j (-l)_{j+k} (1+l)_{j+k}}{j! k! (j+k)!}$$

```
$Version
(*"14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"*)

Int = Integrate[(2^(-j - k) (-x)^j Pochhammer[-l, j + k] Pochhammer[1 + l, j + k])/(j! k! (j + k)!)*x^n, {x, -1, 1}][[1]]
S = Sum[Int, {j, 0, Infinity}, {k, 0, Infinity}]
(* long answer*)
F = FullSimplify[S, Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers && l \[Element] Integers}]// FunctionExpand

(* (2 (-1 + (-1)^n) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 - l/2, 1 + l/2, 1 + n/2}, {3/2, 2 + n/2}, 
1])/((2 + n) Gamma[
1/2 + l/2] Gamma[-(l/2)]) + ((1 + (-1)^n) Sqrt[\[Pi]]
HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2 + l/2, -(l/2), 1/2 + n/2}, {1/2, 3/2 + n/2},
1])/((1 + n) Gamma[1/2 - l/2] Gamma[1 + l/2]) *)

Table[{Integrate[LegendreP[l, x] x^n, {x, -1, 1}], F,(n!)/(Factorial2[n + l + 1]*Factorial2[n - l])*(1 + (-1)^(n - l))}, {n, 1, 10}, {l,
1, 10}] // MatrixForm (*OK*)
```

$$\int_{-1}^1 P_l(x) x^n \, dx=\frac{2 \left(-1+(-1)^n\right) \sqrt{\pi } \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{l}{2},1+\frac{l}{2},1+\frac{n}{2};\frac{3}{2},2+\frac{n}{2};1\right)}{(2+n) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{l}{2}\right) \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{l}{2}\right)}+\frac{\left(1+(-1)^n\right) \sqrt{\pi } \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{l}{2},-\frac{l}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}+\frac{n}{2};1\right)}{(1+n) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{l}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(1+\frac{l}{2}\right)}$$